# Usage of can vs may

Tags: grammar, phrases, word-usage, modal-verbs

It is said that *can* and *may* both are used as a sense of possibility.

If that’s the case, then what is the difference between:

- *It can be very dangerous to cycle at night.*
- *It may be very dangerous to cycle at night.*

Comment: Not much difference between those two; either could be used in almost any circumstances with the same sense. But all modal verbs have several senses and peculiar syntax, and the usages of _can_ and _may_ are very different.

Comment: In that context there is very little difference.  In other contexts the difference between *can* and *may* is quite significant.

Comment: "Can I eat the last cookie?"  "Yes you can."  (It's physically possible to eat it.)  "May I eat the last cookie?"  "No you may not."  (You'll ruin your supper.)

Comment: In addition, _might_ or _could_ seem to work equally well. Frustrating, isn't it, when you've been taught that each of these is different!

Answer (score 3):

> It can be very dangerous to cycle in the night.

This indicates that there are certain circumstances that make it dangerous, e.g.

*It can be very dangerous to cycle in the night, for example: if you are cycling without any lights, if you are cycling through a rough area, if you are cycling after a night at the pub.*

> It may be very dangerous to cycle in the night.

This indicates uncertainty.

*It may be very dangerous to cycle in the night but I'm not sure - it may be perfectly safe.*

Comment: if 'can' is used then does it mean that it is 100% dangerous to cycle in the city ?

Comment: @iamRR - It's dangerous to get out of bed in the morning.

Comment: I would compare it to "It can't be true"/"it may not be true" or "He can be sarcastic"/"He may be sarcastic".

Comment: @iamRR - No, it means that it's dangerous under those particular circumstances. They might not always apply.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK -- And what are those particular circumstances ?

Comment: Clarifying the idea from @chaslyfromUK, the 'can' sentence means that sometimes it is dangerous, but not always.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK -- As aparente001 says 'can' means it is sometimes dangerous, but not always. So if the sentence is 'It can be very cold in winter'. Since 'can' expresses uncertainty so does it mean that there are some chances that there may be no cold in winter ?

Answer (score 0):

Most English speakers do not pay attention to the the subtleties between these words and treat them like synonyms. In this context, I believe it is more appropriate than some others, since they can both just mean possibly in their own ways. Can is a little more indirect in that meaning, whereas may is more direct but imprecise because it can also note permission. However if you want to read deeply enough into it there might be some arcane distinction.

---

> **[Can](http://edl.byu.edu/webster/term/2310607)**
>
> Probable understanding: It is able to be dangerous. This ability does not have to be exercised, indicating  it might not be dangerous but it is nevertheless possible.
>
> Unlikely implication: It might optionally imply the night is known to haves the means establish to be dangerous, such as its own darkness, which makes it hard to operate your bicycle safely.

---

> **[May](http://edl.byu.edu/webster/term/2376836)**
>
> Probable understanding: It [might](http://edl.byu.edu/webster/term/2377531) be dangerous in the sense of there is a chance it is, [rather than strength](http://edl.byu.edu/webster/term/2377530). It is possible but not ascertained.
>
> Unlikely implication: Using this instead of can might indicates you do not know if there are circumstances which could make it dangerous, like thugs or nocturnal monsters taking cover under darkness are actually there. It might be dangerous, if circumstances permit it to be.

---

Sometimes we might use what is considered the past tense of can, [could](http://edl.byu.edu/webster/term/2316499), when discussing hypothetical ability similar to how we might use [would](http://edl.byu.edu/webster/term/2331568) as a hypothetical will. In this case, it seems as if either is appropriate. "I would go, if I could." demonstrates future tense use of both words.

If the author wanted to signify that riding the bicycle at night is certainly dangerous, what probably should have have been written is "It [is](http://edl.byu.edu/webster/term/2073517) very dangerous to cycle in the night". There would be no need to modify the [substantive](http://edl.byu.edu/webster/term/2364829) verb, noting the existence of danger, with an [auxiliary](http://edl.byu.edu/webster/term/2287068) verb and doing so may actually be detrimental to comprehensibility

---

Definitions of can, may, could, would, is, substantive and auxiliary which are used as external reference material are all found in the *Hallen, Cynthia, ed. Renovated Online Edition of Noah Webster’s 1844 American Dictionary of the English Language*, http://edl.byu.edu/index.php .

Answer (score -4):

There is no difference.  From the *OED*

> Can [B. II. With infinitive, as auxiliary of predication] 5. Expressing a possible contingency; = May
>  possibly

Comment: Lovely.  Another drive-by downvote.  I would be happy to express your reservations to www.oed.com if I only knew what they were.

Comment: I didn't vote against the answer myself but since you seem befuddled I'll posit a hopefully helpful hypothesis: You did not contrast the referenced definition of may, against a definition of can to actually demonstrate the perceived differences or more accurately in this case, the lack of a difference.

Comment: @Tonepoet I am not befuddled, because there is nothing in a drive-by downvote to be confused about.  There's nothing.  Which is why DBDVs are a curse upon this forum.  Thank you for your hypothesis, which made me realize that I had omitted the head word "can,"which" I have supplied.  I needed to make explicit what was only implied, namely that this is a definition of "can" as a synonym of "may."  Do you, yourself find a need for more contrast, or is this a need you impute to others?

Comment: Now with the fix, the answer seems fine to me since it is a self-contained analysis of both words in the sense that applies from a respectable source. There's only so much you can do [to contrast the same shade of grey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Same_color_illusion_proof2.png). I guess my hypothesis was wrong though, since this was voted against again. I'm not entirely sure why this received another nay vote.

Comment: Can can be synonymous with may. It is not always synonymous with may. There *is* a difference.

Comment: Or did you mean "Can may be synonymous with may"?  It's not always, that's true.  In particular, the negations of the sentences aren't equivalent.  But all the speculations about the supposed differences in meaning between the originals are unsourced opinion.  In this usage, as the *OED* says:  Can = May.  You might arrive safely on your bike or you might get run over.  I've added the *OED*'s category of usage to make it clear that the definition applies to the example.

Comment: Still don't like it or believe it, eh?

Comment: My answer might be more speculative but Noah Webster's A.D.E.L. is a citable source, isn't it? I just didn't want to quote it verbatim this time. Anyway I think what he takes issue with is the word possibly based upon that but in analyzing this definition I personally take that to mean that to mean, is that while the words share this one sense, they differ in other contexts. Maybe an explanation as to why this sense applies over the others might be useful in that regard .

Comment: @Tonepoet Come again?

Comment: My eh? was actually directed at the third DBDVer.  The comment by @Tonepoet is a little obscure, but if I understand it correctly, it's a valid point:  Sometimes the meanings of the two words differ, and sometimes they're identical.  My answer provides sufficient evidence for the latter possibility but not the necessity.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK shows that can and may imply different things even in this context. And in my comment, I said "can can be synonymous" for a reason. "May" would've been inapt.

Comment: @dbliss  As much as I respect chaslyfromUK he hasn't shown anything.  He's maintained that there's a difference that's unsupported by the gold standard, the *OED*.  I could be convinced that the *OED* is wrong or thatI've misread it, but it would take evidence beyond assertion.  And, no, "may' wouldn't have been an inapt substitution in your sentence.  Both words indicate possibility.

Comment: @deadrat chaslyfromUK's answer *is* supported by the OED.  One definition for "can" is "has the ability to": as in, "The word 'can' has the ability to [i.e., can] be different from the word 'may' -- for example, in this context . . ."  There is no such definition for "may."  The fact that "can" and "may" share one definition -- expressing possibility -- does not mean they are synonyms in all contexts or in this context.

Comment: @dbliss Only people have abilities and intentionality, and I agree that there's a difference between a person saying "I can lift 100 pounds" and "I may lift 100 pounds."  To impute abilities to inanimate objects or abstractions is simply figurative speech that indicates situational possibility.  The claim is that native speakers will discern a difference between "can" and "may" when considering the dangers of a nocturnal bike ride.  I don't believe that's the case, and I'd like to have some evidence before I change my mind.

Comment: @deadrat all you need is evidence that native speakers will discern a difference between "can" and "may" in that sentence?  i am a native speaker.  i discern a difference.  bam.  "to impute ability to . . . abstractions . . . simply . . . indicates situational possibility."  what is your evidence for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26534/discussion-between-deadrat-and-dbliss).

Comment: Great.  Another drive-by down-vote.  Three weeks after the last activity!  It doesn't matter how you vote.  The examples given mean exactly the same thing.  That's because in this and other contexts "can" and "may" are synonyms.  Not in every context.  But in this one.